# Can I use a named argument when calling a method that has a lambda expression for a parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, named-parameters

I'm playing around with named arguments and optional parameters in C# 4.

In particular, I'm trying to use named arguments when calling the HtmlHelpers in ASP.NET MVC like so...

```
@Html.DropDownList(name: "ItemGroup", 
                   selectList: Model.ItemGroupList, 
                   htmlAttributes: new { style="width:300px;" })
```

But what if I want to use the strongly typed helpers that take a lambda expression as their first parameter instead of a string value?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(expression: m => m.ItemGroup, 
                      selectList: Model.ItemGroupList, 
                      htmlAttributes: new { style = "width:300px;" })
```

The above code indicates an error along the lines of "the type arguments...cannot be inferred from the usage."

Coincidentally, this works just fine...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemGroup, 
                      selectList: Model.ItemGroupList, 
                      htmlAttributes: new { style = "width:300px;" })
```

This is probably something really obvious but I'm having difficulty finding anything that explains it well when I search for it. I'm probably not searching for the right terms or something. Anyway, I could use a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your "the type arguments...cannot be inferred from the usage" error, I was only able to get that when the object sent to the selectList argument was a List instead of a SelectList.  This rendered correctly for me:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ReferralAgencyId,
                selectList: new SelectList(Model.ReferralAgencies, "ReferralAgencyId", "Description", Model.ReferralAgencyId))
```

This causes the page to clock and never render:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(expression: x => x.ReferralAgencyId,
                selectList: new SelectList(Model.ReferralAgencies, "ReferralAgencyId", "Description", Model.ReferralAgencyId))
```

Regarding *why* specifying "expression:" for a lambda expression would cause the page to hang, I'm not sure.  It definitely isn't because it is not an optional parameter because Url.Action(actionName:"MyPage", controllerName: "MyController") renders fine.  It looks like just lambda expressions cause this behavior.

Comment: The specific error I'm getting when the view tries to render with expression listed as a named argument is ... 

`Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Thanks for looking at it and I agree it's just with Lambdas I see it happening.